# How to find the smallest $a,b ∈ N$ that solve a single equation

Tags: quadratics, natural-numbers

Im trying to find a method that solves the equality of two quadratic equations with the constraint of $a$ and $b$ being natural numbers, the only way I know is trying value per value, but I was wondering if there is a faster way.

The equation:
$$a^2+a = b^2+19b-12$$

The solution I found is a=5, b=2.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Multiply both sides by $4$ and complete the square. You'll get some number as the difference of two squares, and this is factorable.

Comment: @Henry It’s -12, not +2.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on lhf's comment,
if
$a^2+ua = b^2+vb+w$
then
$4a^2+4ua = 4b^2+4vb+4w$
so
$(2a+u)^2-u^2
=(2b+v)^2-v^2+4w
$
so
$(2a+u)^2-(2b+v)^2
=u^2-v^2+4w$
or
$u^2-v^2+4w
=(2a+u+2b+v)(2a+u-2b-v)
$.

All solutions come from factoring
$u^2-v^2+4w = pq$,
and solving
$p = 2a+u+2b+v,
q = 2a+u-2b-v
$.

This gives
$p+q
=4a+2u$
so
$a = \dfrac{p+q-2u}{4}
$
and
$p-q
=4b+2v$
so
$b = \dfrac{p-q-2v}{4}
$.

This has
$u=1, v=19, w = -12$
so
$u^2-v^2+4w 
= 1-19^2-48
=-408
=-2^3*3*17 $.

Look at all the factorizations,
remembering that
$p$ and $q$
can be negative as well as positive
and
4 must divide the
two expressions.