# Given two prime numbers that satisfy the equation $p^{2}-q^{2}=2p-10q+24$, how many pairs of $(p, q)$ are there?

Tags: prime-numbers, contest-math

I had a seventh grade Math Olympiad, and one specific question stumped me. I memorized this question after the test, here it is:

> Given two prime numbers that satisfy the equation $p^{2}-q^{2}=2p-10q+24$, how many pairs of $(p, q)$ are there?

I first thought of the fact that $p \neq q$ since $2p-10q$ could not be $0$ (as opposed to $p^{2}+q^{2}$), but then I realized that it could be possible because of the $+\ 24$.

EDIT: I also converted $p^{2}+q^{2}$ to $(p+q)(p-q)$, but I didn't know where to continue.

I couldn't really think of any tips or tricks to these types of questions as I only had about 4-5 minutes to do this question (the test was 40 minutes long, and there were 10 questions). Would there be any trick to do these types of questions in under 4 minutes or less?

Note that this is a seventh grade Math Olympiad test, so I would accept answers that are AT MOST at a tenth grade level.

Comment: There are two squares there waiting to be completed.

Comment: @dxiv Oops! I forgot to put one of my other workings there. Sorry!

Comment: Write it as $p^2-2p = q^2-10q+24$.

Comment: There's a problem with the question. From $(p-1)^2 = (q-5)^2$, this implies either $p-1 = q-5$ or $p-1 = -(q-5)$. But in the first case, there are many, many solutions: see [cousin prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cousin_prime) on Wikipedia.

Comment: And then complete the squares on both sides.  $\displaystyle (x^2 - bx) = \left(x - \frac{b}{2}\right)^2 - \frac{b^2}{4}.$

Comment: @TobyMak Good point.  Hard to imagine that a 7th grader is expected to be able to prove, on-the-fly that there are an infinite number of cousin primes.

Comment: @Toby Mak may be there is an additional condition on primes $p$ and $q$. OP said he memorized the question after the test.

Comment: @Infinity_hunter Doubtless, you are expecting to be forgiven for injecting the *voice-of-reason*.

Comment: @user2661923 Isn't that supposed to be an open problem? It seems that there are an infinite number of twin primes, but we haven't proved that yet.

Comment: @TobyMak No doubt the problem composer is from the future and the composer alone knows that the person who *will* prove the cousin prime conjecture is one of the contestants.  Surely you have watched the Star Trek movies.

Comment: This is why it's generally a bad a idea to memorise questions from the test.

Comment: "I also converted $p^{2}+q^{2}$ to $(p+q)(p-q)$" : Perhaps you may wish to re-consider this editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method $-1$

$$\begin{align}&p^{2}-q^{2}=2p-10q+24\\
\iff &(p-1)^2=(q-5)^2 \\
\iff &|p-1|=|q-5| \\
\iff &p-1=±(q-5)\\
\iff &q-p=4 ~\text{or}~ q+p=6 \end{align}$$

---

Method $-2$

$$\begin{align}&p^{2}-q^{2}=2p-10q+24\\
\implies &p^2-2p-(q^2-10q+24)=0\\
\implies &\Delta=1+q^2-10q+24\\ \implies&\Delta=q^2-10q+25\\
\implies &\Delta=(q-5)^2\\
\implies &p=1±(q-5)\\
\implies &p=q-4 ~\text{or}~ p=6-q\end{align}$$

Method $-3$ (similar)

$$\begin{align}&p^{2}-q^{2}=2p-10q+24\\ 
\implies &q^2-10q-(p^2-2p-24)=0\\
\implies &\Delta =25+p^2-2p-24\\
\implies &\Delta =p^2-2p+1 \\
\implies &\Delta=(p-1)^2\\
\implies &q=5±(p-1)\\
\implies &q-p=4 ~\text{or}~ q+p=6
\end{align}$$

Conclusion:

If $q+p=6$, then $p=q=3$

If $q-p=4$, then this is a specific case of [Polignac's conjecture](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polignac%27s_conjecture) for $n=4$.

Comment: Thank you for this answer! +1 and correct answer marked.

Comment: @Tyrcnex You're welcome.  Actually, I don't think I'm very helpful.  Because, I did not expect to encounter an open problem at the end.

Comment: Well, at least now I know that the people who put this question in didn't know what they were doing :)

Answer (score 1):

That's funny.
I just answered this other question:
[How to find the smallest $a,b ∈ N$ that solve a single equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4200437/how-to-find-the-smallest-a-b-%e2%88%88-n-that-solve-a-single-equation/4200462#4200462)

My answer was general enough
to answer this one.

Using my notation there,
$u=-2, v=-10, w=24$
so we look at the factors of
$u^2-v^2+4w
=4-100+96
=0$.

Surprise - I did not consider
this case.
The equation becomes
$(2p-2)^2=(2q-10)^2$
or
$(p-1)^2=(q-5)^2$
or
$0
=(p-1+q-5)(p-1-q+5)
$
so
$0
=p+q-6
$
or
$0
=p-q+4
$.

For the first,
$p+q=6$
so,
if $p, q > 1$,
$p=q=3$.

For the second
$q = p+4$
and there probably
an infinite number of solutions to this
of the form
$p=6m+1, q=6m+5
$.

The first two are
(7, 11), (13, 17).

Comment: Here you said "The first two are...", but does that mean there are more pairs of primes?

Comment: It it conjectured that there are an infinite number of primes differing by 4, but it has not been proven. Look up prime triples.